# Error when assigning RecipientType.TO to message

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

With this piece of code:

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
```

I get a error message "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable RecipientType
  location: class Message" with 'RecipientType' underlined in red.

My guess is that the Message Interface is not recognised, why and how I do not know.
My imports:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
```

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1 and the javaMail 1.4.7 API.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are importing "javax.mail.Message.RecipientType", so you should use "RecipientType.TO" instead of "Message.RecipientType.TO"